# Trying to pass dropdown selections in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting my form to work. I am trying to get it so that when I select the different numbers of "front and back inks," it'll return the runRate value, but it keeps coming up with "wrong" regardless of what numbers I select! Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <select id="ink_front">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <select id="ink_back">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    result
    <INPUT type="text" id="result" readonly style="color:red;" />

    <button onclick="calculate()">submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var front_inks = document.getElementById("ink_front");
  var ink_front = front_inks.options[front_inks.selectedIndex].value;

  var back_inks = document.getElementById("ink_back");
  var ink_back = back_inks.options[back_inks.selectedIndex].value;

  front_inks = parseInt(front_inks);
  back_inks = parseInt(back_inks);

  function runRate(front_ink, back_ink) {
    if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 6400;

    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 3200;

    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 2135;

    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 1600;

    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 3200;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 2135;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 1600;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 2135;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 1600;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 1070;
    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 1600;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 1070;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 915;
    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 1070;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 915;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 800;
    } else {
      var runRate = "wrong";
    }

    return runRate;
  }



  function calculate() {

    var run_rate = runRate(front_inks, back_inks);

    document.getElementById("result").value = run_rate;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Edit: Thank you so much to everyone who answered! This helped me out a lot, greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your are already getting the values if the `frint_inks` and `back_inks` right when the script loads. At this point there is no value selected yet... So your variables will not have any values and hence none of your `if`, `else if` statements will work... And hence you always get the else part of code executed.

**Solution:** get the values if your `front_inks` and `back_inks`  inside your calculate function and then pass it to `runRate` function. Also you were playing with the wrong variables while parsing to int.

Place these lines of code in the beginning of your calculate function like below.

```
function calculate() {

  var front_inks = document.getElementById("ink_front");
  var ink_front = front_inks.options[front_inks.selectedIndex].value;

  var back_inks = document.getElementById("ink_back");
  var ink_back = back_inks.options[back_inks.selectedIndex].value;

  front_inks = parseInt(ink_front);
  back_inks = parseInt(ink_back);   
  var run_rate = runRate(front_inks, back_inks);
  document.getElementById("result").value = run_rate;

  }
```

Comment: Roger that, Reddy! Formatted.

Comment: Thank you so much Zatziky... You still missed the function first line... Can you please take care of that

Comment: Thanks again zatziky

Comment: No problem, Reddy. But I see that some parts of your code are formatted. What went wrong?

Comment: Zatziky I am on mobile and on stack overflow app.. There is no feature to format code.. Actually no formatting feature at all.. Simple text area .... But I remember few formatting tricks so I could format other parts except the code.. :p

Comment: Oh my, you SO addicted. ;) I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected plunker of your code snippet: https://plnkr.co/edit/DfK5mNlXG3CaD8ke300a?p=preview

This your new `calculate()`:

```
function calculate() {
    var front_inks = document.getElementById("ink_front");
    var ink_front = front_inks.options[front_inks.selectedIndex].value;
    var back_inks = document.getElementById("ink_back");
    var ink_back = back_inks.options[back_inks.selectedIndex].value;

    front_inks = parseInt(front_inks);
    back_inks = parseInt(back_inks);

    var run_rate = runRate(ink_front, ink_back);

    document.getElementById("result").value = run_rate;
  }
```

There are two main differences to your original code:

1. `runRate()` is run with `ink_front`/`ink_back` instead of `front_inks`/`back_inks` because you were expecting number values in `calculate()`
2. `ink_front`/`ink_back` are resolved here so that they can have values you chose in the selects.

Answer (score 0):

You were calling `parseInt()` on the wrong two values. You also were assigning your values as soon as the page was loaded, so I moved the variable initialization and allocation into `calculate()`. It works as expected now.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <select id="ink_front">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <select id="ink_back">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    result
    <INPUT type="text" id="result" readonly style="color:red;" />

    <button onclick="calculate()">submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function runRate(front_ink, back_ink) {
    if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 6400;

    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 3200;

    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 2135;

    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 0) {
      var runRate = 1600;

    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 3200;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 2135;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 1600;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 1) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 2135;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 1600;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 2) {
      var runRate = 1070;
    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 1600;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 1070;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 3) {
      var runRate = 915;
    } else if (front_ink == 1 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 1280;
    } else if (front_ink == 2 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 1070;
    } else if (front_ink == 3 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 915;
    } else if (front_ink == 4 && back_ink == 4) {
      var runRate = 800;
    } else {
      var runRate = "wrong";
    }

    return runRate;
  }



  function calculate() {

    var front_inks = document.getElementById("ink_front");
    var ink_front = front_inks.options[front_inks.selectedIndex].value;

    var back_inks = document.getElementById("ink_back");
    var ink_back = back_inks.options[back_inks.selectedIndex].value;

    front_inks = parseInt(ink_front);
    back_inks = parseInt(ink_back); 
   
    var run_rate = runRate(front_inks, back_inks);

    document.getElementById("result").value = run_rate;
  }
</script>

</html>
```